# Learning MySQL: where to get test DB

Tags: mysql

I'm going to teach several persons mysql. I have the plan of that "course" the problem is that I do not have test DB to work in. A copy of any db from a large application will be hard to start with. IMHO something of 5-6 tables will be ok. Maybe someone knows where is it possible to get such a DB? And another question is: can someone give a link to a list of tasks on stored procedures?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sakila Test Database (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/)

Comment: @GopeshSharma thank you! And have you any idea of a list of tasks to master stored procedures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some test databases to work with

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html

Comment: the employee database should suit your needs, if it is the one I have in mind

Comment: @midor yes, it's really what I need. Maybe there's a list of tasks (on complex joins and stored procedures) somewhere over there?

Comment: I think the mysql reference manual uses these databases, so I would just look at their examples in the DDL/DML syntax section e.g.: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html